# Cannot access Ubuntu menu, not to mention Windows operating sys

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I loaded Ubuntu Linux using a CD on to an original laptop's operating sys being Windows 8.

I ran the Ubuntu "alongside" Windows, although I noticed when I tried to access the windows 8 option, it wouldn't take me to the operating sys. So I did some research to try and find it... although I found myself ACCIDENTALLY removing the actual menu, it just goes straight to Ubuntu.

I need the menu back (grub i think(it's purple)), then the Windows 8 back. Although I ***DO NOT*** want to remove the Ubuntu I want to "Run alongside" and actually preform like it says it claims.

****PS. To let you know where I am with this knowledge isn't really high.. I'm beginner-adequate more so pushing towards adequate.****

Thank you,

Comment: @Pabi I think your edit made my answer useless. Aksana said that when she starts the computer it boots directly Ubuntu, and she can't access Win8. Please review your edition.

Comment: first use `sudo update-grub` command from inside Ubuntu and reboot to see if you get GRUB menu back. If you still can't boot to Windows 8, search for how to use `boot-repair` from the live CD.

Comment: I do not need the CD anymore. It's actually embedded into the PC itself.

I'v looked for so many of those before. I finally just asked my own question. 

When I did the grub thing. I rebooted it and it said something "grub2" then said booting to (h0, 8) something like that..

Answer (score 0):

I think the "menu" you're referring to is GRUB (the boot manager). It's simple to get it back to work. Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install grub
```

If the output is something like *grub is already the newest version* then run the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub`.

After GRUB was installed, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

If everything is fine, restart your PC and you should see your "menu" again, with Ubuntu and Windows options.

Comment: I did what you said but that's not working.. same thing.. it says "booting" when I restarted it. UGH :/

Comment: Are you sure you created/reserved an empty partition for Ubuntu before installing it?

Comment: yes, it had the menu for a long time, but i couldn't access the windows directly.  sooo last night i wanted to see if I could try and figure it out. and i managed to erase the "grub".. ugh.. I think I made it worse.

Comment: Have you already reinstalled GRUB?

Comment: yes I have! :) I really do appreciate your time! I would really like to get this behind me.. xD

Comment: So... it worked, right?

Comment: no, still in the same place.. No improvement.

Comment: Well, please do this: open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run `sudo apt-get install gparted`. If it outputs something like _GParted is already the newest version_, skip to the next step. Run `sudo gparted`. Take a screenshot of GParted and send it (if you do not have enough reputation post it somewhere and send the link).

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/

Comment: That's just a G+ link, please post the photo link.

Comment: can you not access it??? That URL should take you there. How do I post a "photo link"???

Comment: No, that's a G+ link. Please open your photo in G+ and then copy its link.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/102541065973391312211/albums/6147687882280422145/6147687885865899762?pid=6147687885865899762&oid=102541065973391312211

Comment: Besides the amount of partitions you have, everything is fine. Try running `sudo update-grub` (If you haven't already done).

Comment: okay, now what? btw, I've done that. 

Now restart, or reboot?

Comment: Strange, you reinstalled GRUB and it's still not working... Why don't you try boot-repair before restarting? `sudo apt-get install boot-repair` `sudo boot-repair`

Comment: which one? 
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ZVz8qMrwzEU/VVD_r0xUdnI/AAAAAAAAABQ/-dMbThVCfjs/w978-h550/info2.png


THESE are the options.
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Q39NhrU_edA/VVD_vrCIWSI/AAAAAAAAABY/EAiekQxdZJY/w978-h550/info3.png

Comment: Choose the first one (recommended settings). These options are OK.

Comment: okay i selected recommended repair, and every time i do that I get this, followed by the abort thing.

FIRST:
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-YillOBDOX8g/VVEBqJkj_eI/AAAAAAAAAB8/OSJpCHU0ZSU/w978-h550/what.png

SECOND:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-4h_biagEquQ/VVEBqJkiqFI/AAAAAAAAACA/Bf4WPt7q9mM/w978-h550/what1.png

Comment: God damn it, your PC is pretty messed... I don't know how I could help you.

Comment: I tried all those operations last-night... stood up to like 3AM. I couldn't figure it out.  ugh, what do you suggest? take it someplace? :/

Comment: Can't you reinstall Windows and then Ubuntu?

Comment: You saw yourself that Windows is already on here.. The problem is accessing it.

Comment: Thanks for your help man! I really do appreciate your time! Have a good one. :)


Cheers,

Aksana JB

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't help you, I am just an Ubuntu user trying to help and get helped. Thanks!

Comment: You did a great job, very attentive thanks! This was actually my first time using "AskUbuntu", great first impression.  Thanks. Hopefully I'll find a solution someday soon :)